# Cannot free a struct's data

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

I have this `struct` as part of a program along with it's create and destroy functions. However when I try to free a `struct` instance the program crashes from a `free`-related error, for example the `main` function would crash with `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`

I don't understand why the pointers are invalid.

p.s.: What would be the best way to initialize `new` in `euCreate()`? Everything I try either causes a memory leak or doesn't work.

```
Eu euCreate()
{
    Eu new = malloc(sizeof(new));
    (*new).Judges = malloc(sizeof(Judge) * 2);
    (*new).Jlen = 2;
    (*new).Jidx = 0;
    (*new).States = malloc(sizeof(State) * 2);
    (*new).Slen = 2;
    (*new).Sidx = 0;
    return new;
}

void euDestroy(Eu eu)
{
    free(eu->Judges);
    free(eu->States);
}

int main()
{
    Eu eu = euCreate();
    euDestroy(eu);
}

typedef struct eu{
    struct judge* Judges;
    int Jlen;
    int Jidx;
    struct state* States;
    int Slen;
    int Sidx;
}* Eu;
```

Comment: Please show some accompanying code

Comment: Post a [mcve] at a *minimum*.

Comment: Don't describe the code, **show** the code.  Describing code says "this is basically what my code does".  The problem is, computers don't do *basically* what you tell them.  They do **exactly** what you tell them.  So tell us **exactly** what you're telling the computer to do, i.e. *show your code*.

Comment: sorry for not uploading the code, accidentally pressed post

Comment: What is `Eu`? Also, as a sidenote - `new` is a reserved word in C++. Using it as a variable name should be legal in C IIRC, but really isn't a great practice.

Comment: @Mureinik forgot another code snippet with its definition, editing

Comment: Count the number of calls to `malloc` you have. Then count the number of calls to `free`. Do they match up?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude refresh the page i forgot to add part of the code

Comment: *code snippet* – please read [mcve].

Comment: @Tom Your current code has *three* `malloc` and *two* `free`...

Comment: Also (and unrelated to your problem) for any pointer to structure `x` and structure-member `y`, instead of writing `(*x).y` you can use the "arrow" operator `->` as in `x->y`. The arrow operator is well-known, makes the code cleaner to read and understand, is one less character to write, and means the exactly same as the combine dereference and dot operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allocating enough space for your structure:

```
Eu new = malloc(sizeof(new));
```

`sizeof(new)` gives you the size of a pointer, not what it points to.  So when you subsequently assign values to members of the struct, you write past the bounds of allocated memory.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case causes your code to crash.

Allocate space for what the pointer *points to*.

```
Eu new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
```

Also, it's bad practice to typedef a pointer, as it obscures the fact that you're working with a pointer.  Better to just typedef the struct and explicitly use the pointers in each declaration where needed.